# Set focus on SharePoint 2013 Modal dialog

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, modal-dialog

I am opening popup modal with below JavaScript code, which is working correctly. But is it possible that when modal dialog opens, cursor or focus should be on modal dialog rather than on parent page.

Please note that modal dialog have only text

```
javascript:OpenPopUpPage("../Pages/XXX.aspx", null, Width, Height)
```

Comment: is there any specific reason for not using SharePoint modal Dialog?

Comment: Yea there are big chuck of text like policy, terms and condition which we can show directly. So we need modal dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the issue as below, hope it helps to some else

```
$("#id").click(function () {
            OpenPopUpPage("XXX.aspx", null, null, null)
            setTimeout(setFocusModalDialog, 100);
            return false;
        })
    });
    function setFocusModalDialog() {
        var iframe = $(".ms-dlgFrame")[0];
        iframe.contentWindow.focus();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below div and style to parent page

```
<div id="dlgpopup" class="ms-dlgOverlay" style="display:none; z-index: 1504; width: 100%; height:100%;"></div>

<style> 
.ms-dlgOverlay {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     opacity: 0.4;
     background-color: #999;
     display: none; 
} </style>
```

Set `z-index:1505` to your dialog box

Add below script before open modal popup

```
document.getElementById("dlgpopup").style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: Thanx Viraj for your reply. So do you mean by all should go in parent page

Comment: Yes, after applying this, it will highlight your modal popup.\

Comment: @viraj-gorjia this custom modal dialog, it is not SharePoint 2013 modal dialog. I was looking for the solution for SharePoint 2013 modal dialog box