# I need to call a function when modals are invoked

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

Is there an event handler I could use to determine when sharepoint launches a modal?

Answer (score 2):

with Javascript you can try using the following

```
function showdialogfunction(pageUrl) {
var options = { url: pageUrl, width: 800, height: 600 };
SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
}
```

if you want to set focus mouse on the dialog then use the following script

```
$("#id").click(function () {
            OpenPopUpPage("XXX.aspx", null, null, null)
            setTimeout(setFocusModalDialog, 100);
            return false;
        })
    });
    function setFocusModalDialog() {
        var iframe = $(".ms-dlgFrame")[0];
        iframe.contentWindow.focus();
    }
```

[Set focus on SharePoint 2013 Modal dialog](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/201747/set-focus-on-sharepoint-2013-modal-dialog)

Comment: Not sure what this is trying to do or how it helps? For example, I need to set keyboard/mouse focus inside the model once it loads.

Comment: FYI. I have updated my answer above

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is no OOTB event handler being provided to us by the SP API. You might want to look at the following post: 
[SP 2010 JavaScript events](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57872/sp-2010-javascript-events)

Answer (score 0):

In my library [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/) I created a customized `showDialogModal` function with more options, and one of them is `onurlload` that triggers when the called URL is loaded.

To do it I check when the iframe (created by Sharepoint to load the URL of the modal) triggers the DOMContentLoad (using `iFrameReady` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/24603642/1134119).

This solution only works if the URL is in the same domain (because of the cross-domain security restriction).

Comment: The problem i have though is that I need to hooking into SharePoint's built in showDialogModal. For example, when you hit new Document, it opens a modal but it doesn't set the cursor focus inside that modal, so now I need to set the focus when this happens. Can you library help with that?

Comment: No it cannot. In your case you have to overwrite the default `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog` or, the `OpenPopUpPageWithDialogOptions()` function... Good luck